# ASP.NET Find an IP Address

Tags: asp.net

**I Want to get an ip address or domain name.**

i have a website like www.abc.com in my site i use generic handler. 
i have one client website www.cde.com.

my client use http request to get some details from my site or my server.

the client request is get in generic handler and perform some task and then i response for that request. this is my concept.

my requirement is how to get an ip address or domail name(www.cde.com) in my generic handler page. it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, just do:

```
string remoteIP=   context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) method:

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("http://www.cde.com");
```

Comment: ok. but which user(website) request my site? how to i find that? because i response my users only. the requested user is my user or not how to i find. i  already have my user ip and website details in my db. so when i get the ip or domain name then i check to my db. so how to get requester ip address or domain name in generic handler page?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking, but if you want to get the IP address of the machine that is hitting your site, you will probably want to go @lcarus' route.